# Showing when Young's Inequality is in fact equality.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image: Young]

The ellipses is where I'm stuck. I don't think a simple algebraic manipulation will work here.

Comment: it is false, it holds also for $a = 0$, $b = 0$.

Comment: In Young's Inequality, a and b have to be positive.

Comment: well, it holds for $a = b = 0$ hence with "nonnegative" we probably mean that $a,b \ge 0$. Also, assuming that $a,b > 0$ you can consider the logarithm of every quantities, which can be a way to obtain something. :) Moreover you proof in the case $a = b = 1$ is extremely too long: just plug in the values in the third member and use the fact that $p,q$ are conjugate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Exercise is wrong. Equality holds if and only if $a^p = b^q$.

To see this, consider $\def\e{\mathrm{e}}x \mapsto \e^x$, which is strictly convex on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then, we get
    \begin{equation*}
  a \, b
  =
  \e^{\ln(a) + \ln(b)}
  =
  \e^{p^{-1} \, \ln(a^p) + q^{-1} \, \ln(b^q)}
  \le
  p^{-1}\, \e^{\ln(a^p)} + q^{-1} \, \e^{\ln(b^q)}
  =
  \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q}.
 \end{equation*}
From this, you get the characterization of equality.

Comment: Oh wow, I just looked at the errata for Royden's "Real Analysis" and it is in fact an error. It should be as you say. It's at the bottom of page 3 here:

http://www2.fiu.edu/~weiwang1/RAE.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative argument for the equality condition:

---

**Young's Inequality:** $\forall p\in]1,\infty[, \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1,\forall a,b\in]0,\infty[: ab\leq\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$. Furthermore

$$ab=\frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q} \iff a^p=b^q.$$

---

**Observation:**
\begin{align}
a^p=b^q \iff & a^{p/q}=b \iff & a^{p-1}=b \\
& a=b^{q/p} & a=b^{q-1}
\end{align}

---

**Lemma:** Set

\begin{align}
f:&]0,\infty[\to\Bbb{R} \\
&x\mapsto (1-x^{1-p})+(p-1)(1-x).
\end{align}
Then $f(x)=0 \iff x=1.$

**Proof of Lemma:** First observe that $f(1)=0$. Also $f'(x)=(p-1)(x^{-p}-1)$, from which we deduce that $1$ is the maximum point of $f$. $\checkmark$

---

**Proof of the Equality Condition:**

$(\impliedby)$ First suppose $a^p=b^q$. Then by the observation above

\begin{align}
\dfrac{a^p}{p}+\dfrac{b^q}{q}=\dfrac{(q+p)b^q}{pq}=b^q=b^{q-1}b=ab.
\end{align}

$(\implies)$ Conversely suppose we have equality. Then

\begin{align}
&ab=\dfrac{a^p}{p}+\dfrac{b^q}{q} =\dfrac{qa^p+pb^q}{p+q}\\
&\implies p+q =q\dfrac{a^{p-1}}{b} + p\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\\
&\implies q\left(\dfrac{a^{p-1}}{b}-1\right)=p\left(1-\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)\\
&\implies \left(\dfrac{a^{p-1}}{b}-1\right)=\dfrac{p}{q}\left(1-\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)\\
&\implies \left(\left(\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)^{1-p}-1\right)=(p-1)\left(1-\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)\\
&\implies 0=\left(1-\left(\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)^{1-p}\right)+(p-1)\left(1-\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}\right)
\end{align}

Hence $\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}$ is a root of $f$ in the above lemma, which guarantees that $\dfrac{b^{q-1}}{a}=1$. By the observation this is equivalent to $a^p=b^q$.

---

**Note:** I used certain arithmetical properties of the conjugates $(p,q)$. I'll leave those and the observation for you to check.

Comment: In your proof of the lemma, the function f looks to me like it has a saddle point at x=1, not a maximum.

Comment: You are right in that I should have checked the second derivative as well, but I believe there is no mistake: $f''(1)=p(1-p)<0$.

Comment: @AlpUzman, its so satisfying answer! [This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fu9c3arqi9) may help seeing lemma for future visitors.